# Prisma database connection string not working in production environment

Tags: next.js, google-cloud-sql, prisma

I've got a NextJS application using prisma ORM to connect to a cloud sql postgres instance. I'm able to successfully connect to the database locally; however, when deploying to a staging or production environment, I'm unable to successfully connect.

I'm not using any special characters in my db user or password values, and I'm also able to connect to a SQL client with the connection string just fine. ie there are no public access issues on the cloud sql instance.

The connection string is of the form:

```
postgresql://user:pass@ip_address:5432/db_name
```

I'll get a 500 when attempting to connect when `NODE_ENV`=production.

I attempted to follow the advice of this [blog post](https://prisma1015.zendesk.com/hc/en-gb/articles/7633933792413-How-to-connect-to-Postgres-in-Google-Cloud-SQL-using-Prisma-), and if I tweak the connection string to:

```
postgresql://user:pass@ip_address:5432/db_name?host=/cloudsql/gcp_project_id:region:instance_name
```

I won't get a 500, but I'll still have an issue connecting to my db. I've also tried replacing "host" with "socket" to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you running your app? Also, FYI https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-nodejs-connector.

Comment: App is running in Render using a docker in docker style deployment if I had to guess. Same issue running in k8 :/

Comment: If you're running in Cloud Run or App Engine, your second approach should work with the built-in Cloud SQL Integration. Otherwise, I'd recommend using the Node connector (or running the Cloud SQL Proxy) as a sidecar.